Lack of Fast Reloading in React Native/Expo within Docker container
I am working on an Expo (React Native) project and have containerized both the frontend and backend services using Docker and Docker Compose to allow other developers to run the project in just one command. I use Expo Go to test the app. When I run the Expo app locally, fast reloading works perfectly, however I'm facing issues with incorporating Fast Reloading inside container. I have been researching and trying to fix a lot, however, right now I feel like got stuck, so I seek for your help. I addedREACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME to frontend/.env to access the app from my phone which is the same network using Expo Go.
The project is Open-Source, so if you're interested in helping me get this error fixed you could see the source-code here:
https://github.com/EcoRangersX/EcoBuddy
Contributions are welcomed and can be targeted to this PR
In addition to this, I am facing issues making network requests from the frontend container to the backend container using Axios. The frontend service can't resolve the backend hostname properly and throws an error: "Unable to resolve host backend: No address associated with hostname."
Moreover, I couldn't open the app on all other ports expect for 8081, here is the error that I always faced:

Additionally, I'm wondering why the bundling process takes from 30 to 50 seconds from Docker, whereas on local machine it usually takes less than 10 seconds.
Expectations:

Fast-Reloading works smoothly from Docker's container

Axios requests are reaching backends' endpoints.


Any help would be much APPRECIATED!
Environment:

React Native using Expo (SDK 51)

Running both containers with Docker Compose (v2.27.0-desktop.2)

Operating System: Windows 11 (v-23H2)


What have I already tried?

Polling for File Changes: Added CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true to ensure changes are detected and pulled by Docker.

Volume Mounting: Mounted local frontend directory as a volume to /home/app for changes to be reflected automatically in container.

Port Exposure: Exposed necessary ports for Expo development server (8081, 19000, 19001) to ensure WebSocket connection and Metro Bundler communication work properly.

Testing Backend Connectivity: Ran curl http://backend:5000 inside Docker Execution tab and it worked correctly, indicating that the backend service is accessible.

Backend Service Name Resolution: Tried using the service name backend in Axios requests from the frontend to the backend, but encountered the error: "Unable to resolve host backend: No address associated with hostname".



Dockerfile (for the frontend):
# Use the official Node.js image as the base image
FROM node:18

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Start the application
CMD ["npx", "expo", "start"]


docker-compose.yml
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "19000:19000"
      - "19001:19001"
    environment:
      - "./frontend/.env"
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true  # Required for hot reloading to work in Windows
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/app
      - ./frontend/node_modules:/home/app/node_modules  # Prevents node_modules from being overriten
    depends_on:
      - backend
    tty: true  # Enables the interactive terminal (shows the QR code for Expo Go)

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env


If running the application locally works as you expect, can you just do that?  Is there any need to introduce an isolation system like Docker into your core development flow?  The Compose file you're showing seems to be trying very hard to run Node hidden in an image against code that lives exclusively on your host (nothing in your images' /app directories is used at all) and just using Node without Docker will probably be simpler here.

@DavidMaze I'm running the app locally for now, but my initial initiative was to use isolation that Docker provides mostly due to other non-technical people wants to run it and see how our mobile-app works, so I would like to avoid installing dependencies, environments like Node.js, and minimize boilerplate with running it on different Operating Systems. The docker compose provides an ideal solution because it has only a few requirements, and can be easily run using one command.
